# Using Variables in ested Azure ARM Templates

Tags: azure, templates, azure-resource-manager

i want to deploy an nested  azure arm template and i need a hint how to reuse variables defined in the main template.

In azuredeploy.json i declare some variables to use in the template.

```
   "variables": {
        "nestedtemplateUriStorage": "[uri(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), concat('nestedtemplates/storage.json', parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')))]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "DiagStorageName": "[tolower(concat(parameters('Kundenkuerzel'),'sadiag'))]",
        "DiagStorageType": "Standard_LRS"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
        "name": "storage",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
              "uri": "[variables('nestedtemplateUriStorage')]"
            },
            "variables": {
              "location":{"value": "[variables('location')]" },
              "DiagStorageName" :{"value": "[variables('DiagStorageName')]" },
              "DiagStorageType" :{"value": "[variables('DiagStorageType')]" }
          }
        }
      },
```

My storage.json looks like the following.

```
{
   ...
        },
    "variables": {
        "location": "[variables('location')]",
        "DiagStorageName": "[variables('DiagStorageName')]",
        "DiagStorageType": "[variables('DiagStorageType')]"
      }, 
    "resources": [
       {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "[variables('DiagStorageName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "location": "[variables('location')]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "StorageAccount"
      },
      "properties": {
        "accountType": "[variables('DiagStorageType')]"
      }
    }

    ]
}
```

How is it possible to use the variables declared in the main template in the linked template?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to pass those in as parameter. you cannot define variables when running nested template.